# BuildAgent access to xcopy and attrib when run as a service

Tags: windows, windows-services, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

We are running TeamCity. I've installed a BuildAgent to a Windows box where it is run as a service. Instead of running it under Local System account, I've decided to run it as a dedicated user. This machine was used to build our solutions in the past and all necessary tools are already installed and accessible by this user.

Most of the building and testing works fine. But I have some pre- and a postbuild steps doing administrative work. Those steps use external commands like attrib and xcopy (as usual, located in System32). These cannot be executed by the BuildAgent when started with the dedicated user. If I add the complete path to System32 to these commands, they also work well. So obviously, it seems to be an environment problem.

When started with the Local System account, these steps are executed as expected. (There are other reasons not to use the Local System account, so that's no solution, unfortunately.)

The fallback, running the BuildAgent from the console, works fine as well. But since it is also possible to run the BuildAgent as a service when using the Local System account, I'm looking for a way to modify the dedicated user (rights or environment) to enable it to run the BuildAgent as a service.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please check PATH variable contains right value when agent is started as service. You may consider wrapping calls to the tool with cmd.exe /c